# Keep design element in template database only

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there a way to keep a design element (e.g View, Form, Agent...) in the template database and not refresh it to the inheritance database when I refresh design?

I have some views I want to delete from a database but keep them on the database template. I don't want them to "return" to the database after refresh design

Thanks,

Y

Comment: Just a thought... Haven't tried it... In the template, on the security tab of the View Properties dialog: uncheck "All readers and above", add your own name, and remove Anonymous and LocalDomainServers (and anything else that might be there). The idea is that if only you have access, and the server doesn't, theoretically the overnight Design task will not be able to refresh it into the database. What this won't stop, however, is a manual refresh or replace design. If you do that from your Domino Designer client, you do have access - so the view will definitely be added back to the database.

Comment: If the above works, please let me know and I will move this suggestion from a comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent design elements from being inherited. I usually use another solution: Versioning.

Create a new copy of your template and give it another version in Title, Filename and Template name. Then remove the views from this new version and replace design of your database. That way you still have an "old" copy in the older template version.

The other advantage is: If something really goes wrong, you can switch back to the "older" version of the template at any time...